# Filter() function not working correctly in R

Tags: r, filter

I have a simple dataframe/datatable with year column, description column and name column.

When filtering year 2019, count of rows is 34:

```r
library(dplyr) 

filter(df,df[1]==2019 & df[2]== "Master")
```

If filtering with year 2020, count of rows is 40:

```
filter(df,df[1]==2020 & df[2]== "Master")
```

But when filtering both years, some of the rows are cut off, and it shows some rows of year 2019 and some rows of 2020, in total showing 37 rows:

```
filter(df,df[1]==c(2019,2020) & df[2]== "Master")
```

Is this the correct way to filter data? What could be the cause of not showing all data?

P.S. Cannot add dataframe because of confidentiality.

Comment: You are looking for the function `%in%`. Also Consider using the names  ie `filter(df, col_1_name %in% c(2019,2020), col_2_name == 'Master')`

Comment: FYI it's not standard practice to subset data.frames within tidyselecting functions (such as filter). Filter is designed so that you can pass column names directly as arguments, e.g. `filter(df, year == 2019)`